# How to update chart at the end of every for loop in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm currently using Chart.js for some data visualization and I need the chart to update after every iteration of the for loop but the chart updates only at the end of the for loop.

I've tried to use setInterval and setTimeout but I haven't exactly got it to work in my situation.

```
function bubble() {
    for (i = 0; i < num - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < num - i - 1; j++) {
            if (ar[j] > ar[j + 1]) {
                var tmp = ar[j];
                ar[j] = ar[j + 1];
                ar[j + 1] = tmp;
                myChart.data.datasets[0].data[j] = ar[j];
                myChart.data.datasets[0].data[j + 1] = ar[j + 1];
                myChart.update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to update the chart after every iteration of my bubble sort program but unfortunately, it updates only after the end of the outer for loop. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66304869/2358409

Answer (score 0):

if you have a lot of update operations you should remove the animation duration from the chart. [Read the paragraph "preventing-animations"](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#preventing-animations)

```
function bubble() {
    for (i = 0; i < num - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < num - i - 1; j++) {
            if (ar[j] > ar[j + 1]) {
                var tmp = ar[j];
                ar[j] = ar[j + 1];
                ar[j + 1] = tmp;
                myChart.data.datasets[0].data[j] = ar[j];
                myChart.data.datasets[0].data[j + 1] = ar[j + 1];
                myChart.options.animation.duration = 0;
                myChart.update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The options.animation.duration should remove the animation duration

If it doesn't works as intended you should wait for the update operations with a setInterval or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js uses `requestAnimationFrame` to render the changes to charts.

So when whenever you say `chart.update()`, it won't render the changes immediately, it will render the changes in next frame.

When you are calling `chart.update()` inside a for loop, the whole loop gets executed in a single cycle, so whats happening there is your chart data is getting updated in first iteration which is queued to be rendered in next frame, but without waiting for the next frame the data is getting updated again and so on.

By the time of next frame, your chart has only the final changes, all the intermediate changes were overwritten.

If you want each iteration of your change to show up in the rendering you should exactly make one change per frame. To do that `for` or `while` loops are not an option as they are synchronous.

You should be using a recursive function which waits for next frame before making the next change using `requestAnimationFrame` if you want snapshots or `setTimeout` if you want animation too.

You should be following the below template

```
(function iteration() {
  chart.update();

  // Wait for next frame for the changes to render and call the next iteration
  requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    iteration();
  });
})();
```